# How to find Mobile No. exist or not?

Tags: mysql, sql

In MYSQL, I want to check whether mobile no. exist or not. But here I have totally different scenerio.
Like in my table I have MobNo. = '9874563210'. I want to check if '9874563210' or '+189874563210' or '09874563210' or '009874563210' exist or not.

**NOTE: '+18' is country code. And I want to check for 1 number only i.e. ('9874563210') others '+18', '0', '00' before MOBILE-NUMBERS are scenerios**

I tried is: `SELECT MobNo. FROM tbl_Contact WHERE MobNo. LIKE '%9874563210%'`. This query only check for '9874563210' only.

I want it should check all condition say: '9874563210', '+189874563210', '09874563210', '009874563210'

I want if mobile number '9874563210' including scenerios '+18', '00', '0' as prefix exist or not. If exist then say "ALREADY EXIST"

I tried many solution but none work for me. I am very new to MYSQL.

ANY HELP, WILL BE HIGHLY APPRECIATED.

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not as much a question on SQL, as it is on phone numbers and algorithm :-)

Telephone numbers are complete when starting with a plus sign. +1234567890 might be such a number, where after the plus there comes some country code, then some area code, then the local number.

If on the other hand a number doesn't start with a plus sign, the number is somewhat incomplete, because it can't be used from everywhere in the world. Instead it is a number based on some location.

I live in Germany, Hamburg. Country code is 49, area code is 40. Moreover we use a prefix 0 to call an area and 00 to call a country. Hence these are the same when stored on a phone in Hamburg:

- +4940123456
- 004940123456
- 040123456
- 123456

A number in another area in Germany can be stored on my phone as

- +4930123456
- 004930123456
- 030123456

A number in another country can be stored on my phone as

- +5512345678
- 005512345678

I can convert any of all the above numbers to the international complete number, because I know the country prefix, the area prefix, my country code and my area code. The algorithm is as follows:

1. IF the number starts with '+', it's complete already.
2. ELSEIF the number starts with the country prefix ('00' for me), then I replace the country prefix with a '+'.
3. ELSEIF the number starts with the area prefix ('0' for me), then I replace the area prefix with a '+' followed by my country code ('49').
4. ELSE I put a '+', then the country code ('49'), then the area code ('40') before the number.

I'll end up with a query like this:

```
select *
from address
where 
  case 
    when phone like '+%' then phone
    when phone like '00%' then concat('+', substr(phone, 3))
    when phone like '0%' then concat('+49', substr(phone, 2))
    else concat('+4940', phone)
  end =
  case 
    when @phone like '+%' then @phone
    when @phone like '00%' then concat('+', substr(@phone, 3))
    when @phone like '0%' then concat('+49', substr(@phone, 2))
    else concat('+4940', @phone)
  end;
```

If phone numbers can contain additional characters (like dashes and slashes, e.g. '+49-40/1234-56), then you would have to invoke `REPLACE` on the numbers, too, in order to get rid of these characters and be able to compare.

Answer (score 1):

use in

```
SELECT MobNo FROM tbl_Contact 
WHERE MobNo in ('9874563210', '+189874563210', '09874563210', '009874563210')
```

you will get only the exist number other's will not appear

Comment: I updated my question please check, the numbers are same. '+18', '00', '0' are scenerios before mobile number.

Answer (score 0):

Join your table to a query that returns all possible scenerios:

```
select t.mobno
from tbl_Contact t inner join (
  select '' prefix union all
  select '+18' union all 
  select '00' union all 
  select '0'
) p on concat(p.prefix, '9874563210') = t.mobno
```

You can extend the query of scenarios with as many values as you want.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, 'IN' statements creates a series of OR statements. In your case, if you need to check multiple phone numbers, you will need combination of IN and LIKE

If the data type of PhoneNumber is string, the below should work.

```
select * from PhoneNumber where PhoneNumber like '%1234567890' OR PhoneNumber like '%1111111110'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions:

```
where mobno regexp '^(+18|0{0-2})9874563210$'
```